# Does the Playstation Vue Mobile iPad app support AirPlay (non-mirroring)?

Tags: ipad, airplay

Is there support for AirPlay (non-mirroring) in the Playstation Vue Mobile iPad app? I can't find any mention of it on the app's page:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/playstation-vue-mobile/id957987596?mt=8

Answer (score 1):

No. I have the service, and when I attempt to Airplay a show to my TV, the video feed dies. Most likely due to some DRM Sony put on these shows.